# MVC retrieving selected value from database to cascading onload when I click edit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this table name Item and when I edit one row of the table it returns null values for State and City dropdownlist. But in database is already added but dropdownlist show empty I don't know how to retrieve selected value
and here all my codes that I was used

here Table Item

```
[Table("Item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    public int CatId { get; set; }

    public int? CountryId { get; set; }

    public int? StateId { get; set; }

    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CatId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StateId")]
    public virtual States States { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

}
```

code Edit on Item controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edite(int id)
    {

        List<Country> countrylist = db.CountryTb.ToList();
        SelectList s2 = new SelectList(countrylist.AsEnumerable(), "id", "name");
        ViewBag.SelectCountry = s2;


        Item I = db.Items.Single(x => x.id == id);

        return View(I);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Edite")]
    public ActionResult Edite_post(int id)
    {
        Item I = db.Items.Single(x => x.id == id);
        UpdateModel(I, null, null, new string[] { "id" });
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and this is my jQuery code but I think it's work only onchange I want it work onload too to retrieving selected value

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Country/GetStatesById", { ID: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append(" <option value='" + row.state_id + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
                });
            })
        });
    });

</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#StateId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Country/GetCitiesById", { ID: $("#StateId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#CityId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#CityId").append(" <option value='" + row.id + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
                });
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```

here my html code

```
 <!--Country-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectCountry, "select please", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--States-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("StateId", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "state_id", "name"), "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--City-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CityId", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "id", "name"), "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

here table Category

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

here table Country

```
[Table("countries")]
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string sortname { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<States> states { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

here table States

```
[Table("states")]
public class States
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int state_id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public int country_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("country_id")]
    public virtual Country countries { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> cities { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

here table City

```
[Table("cities")]
public class City
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public int state_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("state_id")]
    public virtual States states { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for implementing cascading dropdownlists (particularly the code in the controller)

Comment: can you show your Category class?

Comment: i added the class

Answer (score 0):

Try change `@DropDownList` on `@DropDownListFor(c => c.CountryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectCountry, "select please", new { @class = "form-control" })`
Begin form will see change value options dropdowns and your example `CountryID` will send to your controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because of you may not have set up the proper **navigation** properties.
The way you refered to the **Foriegn key** is valid but the reverse navigation is missing. Kindly add the below lines into the corresponding classes.

```
public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<States> States { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

Refer to this link for more [information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) on Entity Framework Navigation properties and relationships

Comment: i already add it before  on corresponding classes !
i think must be from jquery ?!!

Comment: please update ur post with Category or Country class

Comment: did you fix using this?

Comment: did not fix yet  i think maybe from jquery
is need edit?

Comment: what is your console.log says?